# Automatic copy table to a new Sheet without formula (Google Sheets script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste, google-sheets-formula

There is a Sheet, which consists of a table with formulas. How it possible to get only values (without formulas) to a second Sheet? I need the process to apply automatically (without Copy Paste by hands).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options). By default both the values and formatting are copied, but this can be overridden using advanced arguments.

```
// The code below copies only the values of the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("A:E").copyTo(sheet.getRange("F1"), {contentsOnly:true});
```

The advanced parameters are the following:

> - **formatOnly**: designates that only the format should be copied
> - **contentsOnly**: designates that only the content should be    copied

Answer (score 0):

- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>** the table
- **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>** to the second sheet

[image: 0]

Comment: is it copy past method? my table is updated very often. is it possible copy values without formulas automatically?